# How to use a python module entirely locally on linux

Tags: python, linux, python-requests, package, python-module

I am working on a school assignment, where I would like to use the python3 requests library, but I'm not allowed to make any changes to the school's submission machine, and I am only allowed to provide a folder that contains all my code and a shell script with which to run it.

I am wondering, is there a way to use the python requests library in a way that installs nothing and makes no assumptions about the machine other than it has a standard python installation, assuming I am allowed to put anything inside of my submission folder

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you want the `--target` option. `pip install -t <dir>` will bundle requests as a subfolder under a directory. Of course for a different target OS, you might need to build this in a docker image.

Comment: How is the program being run on this restricted computer? Will your submission folder have `pip install` called on it?

Comment: Take a look at [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module.

Comment: @rv.kvetch after installing in my directory, how would I access the requests module in python? I would need an absolute path right? Assuming I’m not allowed to change the PATH or PYTHONPATH

Comment: The good news is, you can treat this as *just another package* that you have created locally. For example, using `pip install requests -t .` in a new folder  unpacks everything and creates a `requests` folder within, which you can then import from within your new folder using the same `from requests import ...` syntax.

Comment: The bad news is, this will likely only work for your own OS (for example, if you test with Windows it is only expected to work on Windows). So to bundle those libraries in another OS, one option would be to use a Docker image that uses the same target OS environment, which you can run to create a `zip` file in your local directory which contains the bundled dependencies that can run on the target OS. This is also the same thing I do when bundling up my project and `pip` dependencies for deployment to AWS Lambda, which runs in a Linux environment.

Comment: Do you have docker installed or venv?

Comment: @rv.kvetch thankfully I don't have to deal with the different platforms problem, since everything is happening in a ubuntu docker container, but I installed requests with -t to my project folder and I am getting the error that it can't find the other modules that it installed with it, like urllib3 and charset_normalizer. I think it has something to do with where the folders are located, because the requests folder is on the same level as the urllib3 and charset normalizer folders, and I assume it's not looking in the folder above it, but I've tried moving them around a bit to no avail

Comment: currently getting the error ```must have charset_normalizer or chardet installed```. There is a folder called charset_normalizer in the project folder that pip installed (at the same level as the requests package) but I guess it can't find it for some reason, do you know how I might be able to get the requests package to find it?

Comment: did you ensure you're running the script in a new virtual environment? I guess it could be looking at both your global `pip` packages as well as the ones in the project folder.

Comment: or you could try `pip uninstall requests chardet charset_normalizer`, which should force it to use the local libraries.